# Newtonsoft JSON Deserialize to object list in list

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have to deserialize a json string to my own object which has a list of childs and this has also a list of childs.
Like this:
parent class -> list ->  list

How is it possible to desserialize this json string ?

json example:

```
{
{
    "Departementstructure": {
        "org.MainDepartments": [{
            "@MainDepartmentsId": "4",
            "@MainDepartmentsName": "Direktorium",
            "@MainDepartmentsName_En": "Board of Directors",
            "org.WorkAreas": [{
                "@Id": "30",
                "@Name": "Direktorin",
                "@WorkAreasName_En": "Director",
                "org.LIfBiDepartments": {
                    "@LIfBiDepartmentsId": "1",
                    "@LIfBiDepartmentsName": "Direktorin",
                    "@LIfBiDepartmentsName_En": "Director"
                }
            },
            {
                "@Id": "31",
                "@Name": "Kaufmännischer Geschäftsführer",
                "@WorkAreasName_En": "Executive Director of Administration",
                "org.LIfBiDepartments": {
                    "@LIfBiDepartmentsId": "52",
                    "@LIfBiDepartmentsName": "",
                    "@LIfBiDepartmentsName_En": ""
                }
            },
            {
                "@Id": "32",
                "@Name": "Wissenschaftliches Referat des Direktoriums",
                "@WorkAreasName_En": "Scientific Office to the Board of Directors",
                "org.LIfBiDepartments": {
                    "@LIfBiDepartmentsId": "53",
                    "@LIfBiDepartmentsName": "",
                    "@LIfBiDepartmentsName_En": ""
                }
            },..
```

The jsonproperty attributes are from trying out a solution.

```
   public class LomVereinsstructure
{
    public LomVereinsstructure()
    {
        Parents = new List<LomParentMainDepartment>();
    }

    [JsonProperty("Departementstructure")]
    public List<LomParentMainDepartment> Parents { get; set; }

}

[JsonArray("org.MainDepartments")]
public class LomParentMainDepartment
{
    public LomParentMainDepartment()
    {
        Children = new List<LomChildWorkarea>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("@MainDepartmentsId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("@MainDepartmentsName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("@MainDepartmentsName_En")]
    public string NameEn { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    //[JsonProperty("org.WorkAreas")]
    public List<LomChildWorkarea> Children { get; set; }

}

[JsonArray("org.WorkAreas")]
public class LomChildWorkarea
{

    public LomChildWorkarea()
    {
        Children = new List<LomChildDepartment>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("@Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]

    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("@Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("@WorkAreasName_En")]
    public string NameEn { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    //[JsonProperty("@org.LIfBiDepartments")]
    public List<LomChildDepartment> Children { get; set; }

}

[JsonArray("org.LIfBiDepartments")]
public class LomChildDepartment
{
    public LomChildDepartment()
    {
        OrganisationUnit = new LomChildOrganisationUnit();
    }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("@LIfBiDepartmentsId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("@LIfBiDepartmentsName")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty("@LIfBiDepartmentsName_En")]
    public string NameEn { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public LomChildOrganisationUnit OrganisationUnit { get; set; }

}
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Visual Studio have a parser to class in `Edit -> Paste Special -> Past JSON as Classes` then you can compare what it makes with your own object and see whats wrong

Comment: it will also tell you which part of the JSON string is faulty

Answer (score 0):

To easily generate the class that can hold your JSON data, you can use one of the JSON-C# conversion services like https://jsonutils.com/ or http://json2csharp.com/. If these are unable to generate the classes, you should use a validator like https://jsonlint.com/ to see if the JSON is indeed valid (from the snippet it seems that the very first brace should be a square one, if it is actually an array).

Answer (score 0):

There's a discrepancy here:

In  your json string you have a single object of `org.LIfBiDepartments` not an Array

In your class model you have a `public List<LomChildDepartment> Children { get; set; }`

So just fix your json string to represent an Array or fix your model to take only 1 object.

In any case use the Parser in Visual Studio to help you see the class model it reproduces for your json string. It's very handy.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Departement
{
    [JsonProperty("org.MainDepartments")]
    public IList<Departaments> MainDepartments { get; set; }

}

public class Departaments
{
    [JsonProperty("@MainDepartmentsId")]
    public string DpId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@MainDepartmentsName")]
    public string DpName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@MainDepartmentsName_En")]
    public string DpNameEn { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("org.WorkAreas")]
    public IList<WorkAreas> WorkAreas { get; set; }
}

public class WorkAreas
{
    [JsonProperty("@Id")]
    public string WorkId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@Name")]
    public string WorkName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@WorkAreasName_En")]
    public string WorkNameEn { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("org.LIfBiDepartments")]
    public LIfBiDepartments LIfBiDepartments { get; set; }
}

public class LIfBiDepartments
{
    [JsonProperty("@LIfBiDepartmentsId")]
    public string BiDpId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@LIfBiDepartmentsName")]
    public string BiDpName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@LIfBiDepartmentsName_En")]
    public string BiDpNameEn { get; set; }
}

Use a property in the parent class to call the object's deserializer in 
daughters classes. 

Example:
    [JsonProperty("Departementstructure")]
    public Departement MainDepartement { get; set; }

Output:
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quD2c.png)

Comment: Please don't just post a code block. Some explanation of your answer is recommended. Please see our [how to answer page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio have a parser to class in Edit -> Paste Special -> Past JSON as Classes then you can compare what it makes with your own object and see whats wrong – Zorkind

I fixed the problem by using the integrated parser from visual studio.

Thanks